# Redirecting with mod_rewrite not working correctly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to using the mod_rewrite engine on Apache although I do have some basic understanding of regular expressions. However, I am perplexed and becoming quite apoplectic at a redirect that isn't working correctly.

Here is the relevant code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vacations/([^/]*)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I redirect, there is nothing in $2. $0 and $1 both contain the entire matched string. For example, if the original URL is /vacations/asia/rar, I will be redirected to http://www.example.com/vacations/asia/rar instead of www.example.com/asia.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `RewriteRule backreferences` ($1) when you should be using the [RewriteCond backreferences](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (%1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vacations/([^/]*)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```